# Show that $\mu$ is additive and continuous from below then it is $\sigma$ additive.

Tags: measure-theory

Show that $\mu$ is additive and continuous from below then it is $\sigma$ additive.

Consider the sets $E_1,E_2,...$ countable and disjoint contain in $\mathcal{C}$ which is an algebra such that $E=\bigcup_{i\geq 1} E_i.$ Then we want to show that $\mu(E)=\sum_{i\geq 1}E_i.$

So first note that any finite union $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_i\subset E$ and so $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(E_{i})\leq \mu(E).$$

Furthermore if we consider the sequence of sets $F_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}E_i$ then $F_k$ is an increasing sequence of sets contained in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\bigcup_{k\geq 1} F_k=E$ and so by continuity from below we have that $$\mu(F_k)\to\mu(E).$$ In other words, $$\mu(E)=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu(E_i).$$ Now at this stage the author concludes that by the previous inequality and this equality we get that $$\mu(E)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\mu(E_i).$$ I am not sure how this happened so if anyone could explain this step, I would be much obliged.

Comment: The latter two equations are the same (different\ notation, that's all).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @copper.hat it is weird though that the author concludes that second equivalent form "by the previous inequality"

Comment: The inequality which you get for a finite number of terms....